# When to use which for?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, iteration

**EDIT** Additional options and a slightly extended question below.

Consider this contrived and abstract example of a class body. It demonstrates four different ways of performing a "for" iteration.

```
private abstract class SomeClass
{
    public void someAction();
}

void Examples()
{
    List<SomeClass> someList = new List<SomeClass>();

    //A. for
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count(); i++)
    {
        someList[i].someAction();
    }

    //B. foreach
    foreach (SomeClass o in someList)
    {
        o.someAction();
    }

    //C. foreach extension
    someList.ForEach(o => o.someAction());

    //D. plinq
    someList.AsParallel().ForAll(o => o.someAction());
```

**EDIT:** Addition of some options from answers and research.

```
    //E. ParallelEnumerable
    ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, someList.Count - 1)
        .ForAll(i => someList[i].someAction());

    //F. ForEach Parallel Extension
    Parallel.ForEach(someList, o => o.someAction());

    //G. For Parallel Extension
    Parallel.For(0, someList.Count - 1, i => someList[i].someAction())
}
```

My question comes in two parts. Have I missed some significant option? Which option is the best choice, considering readability but primarily performance?

Please indicate if the complexity of the `SomeClass` implementation, or the `Count` of `someList` would effect this choice.

**EDIT:** With such a dizzying array of options, I wouldn't like my code to be spoilt by choice. To add a thrid part to my question, If my list could be any length should I default to a parallel option?

As a straw man. I suspect that over all implementations of `SomeClass` and all lengths of `someList` option `//E. ParallelEnumerable` would offer the best average performance, given the prevalanece of multi processor architechtures. I haven't done any testing to prove this.

Note: The parallel extensions will require the use of the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace.

Comment: This question could be better, if there was test data in it.

Comment: @Petr Abdulin, I'm asking how the "test data" would effect the choice. The question is intentionally open. Its a decision developers have to make all the time so I was wondering how we know what the right choice is.

Comment: Much more detail question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247247/performance-of-different-c-sharp-loops with test data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option A only really makes sense for sequences that implement indexing and will only be performant for those that have `O(1)` lookup time. Generally, I would use the `foreach` and variants unless you have special logic.

Also note, that "special logic" like `for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)` can be implemented with Linq extension methods: `foreach(var item in sequence.Skip(1))`.

So, generally prefer B over A.

As to C: This can be confusing for other developers if they aren't used to the functional style.

As to D: This will depend on a lot of factors. I guess for simple calculations, you don't want to do this - you will only really benefit from parallelization if the loop body takes a while to compute.

Comment: Second that. Moreover, `foreach` works on any `IEnumerable`, whereas `for` and index lookup doesn't (may be nice as soon as you refactor code).

Answer (score 3):

you missed:

```
Parallel.ForEach(someList, o => o.someAction())
Parallel.For(0, someList.Length, i => someList[i].someAction())
```

Answer (score 3):

The IL shows us that the for loop is the most efficient. There's no state machine to worry about.

**for** produces the following

```
IL_0036:  br.s        IL_0048
IL_0038:  ldloc.0     
IL_0039:  ldloc.1     
IL_003A:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+SomeClass>.get_Item
IL_003F:  callvirt    UserQuery+SomeClass.someAction
IL_0044:  ldloc.1     
IL_0045:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0046:  add         
IL_0047:  stloc.1     
IL_0048:  ldloc.1     
IL_0049:  ldloc.0     
IL_004A:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Count
IL_004F:  blt.s       IL_0038
```

IL_0051:  ret

The IL produced here for **foreach** shows the state machine at work.  The LINQ version and the ForEach produce similar output.

```
IL_0035:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+SomeClass>.GetEnumerator
IL_003A:  stloc.3     
IL_003B:  br.s        IL_004B
IL_003D:  ldloca.s    03 
IL_003F:  call        System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+SomeClass>.get_Current
IL_0044:  stloc.1     
IL_0045:  ldloc.1     
IL_0046:  callvirt    UserQuery+SomeClass.someAction
IL_004B:  ldloca.s    03 
IL_004D:  call        System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery+SomeClass>.MoveNext
IL_0052:  brtrue.s    IL_003D
IL_0054:  leave.s     IL_0064
IL_0056:  ldloca.s    03 
IL_0058:  constrained. System.Collections.Generic.List<>.Enumerator
IL_005E:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_0063:  endfinally  
IL_0064:  ret
```

I haven't done any tests but I think it's a safe assumption.

That being said, it doesn't mean **for** keyword should be used always. It all depends on your style, your teams style or if that piece of code your writing really needs every CPU cycle you can get your hands on.

I don't think I would compare AsParallel() with the for, foreach or the lambda equivalents. You'd split up CPU intensive tasks or blocking operations using AsParallel(), you wouldn't use it just iterating over a "normal" collection.

Comment: This is only true if you are looking at an indexed collection.  Though the OP uses a `List` in his example, the question seems to be more generally about iteration constructs not interation constructs *for lists*.  For some types of collections `collection[i]` doesn't even make sense (you'd have to do `ElementAt()`) and could be much less performant.

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance is concerned I think one of these would work best.

```
  //A. for
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count(); i++)
    {
        someList[i].someAction();
    }
```

or

```
 //D. plinq
    someList.AsParallel().ForAll(o => o.someAction());
```

Although in case of A, I would prefer not to do someList.Count() every time.

`for` performs better as compared to `foreach` as far as performance is concerned. D can be better than A but it would depend on the scenario. If you have some large data in somelist, Parallelism might help but if you have small data, it can cause extra burden

Comment: Haris, recently we found out that `for` performs slightly better on arrays as well. Do you know why? I'm really wondering, as `foreach` should do similar things in the `IEnumerable` implementation, shouldn't it?

Comment: `for` won't have to go through `IEnumerable` code to fetch next item during each iteration, I think that makes it more faster as compared to `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I go with what logically matches what I'm doing.  If I'm looping over the entire list all use foreach but if I'm looping through a subset I use a for loop.  Also, if you are modifying the collection in your loop you have to use a for loop.

The only other option that I'm aware that hasn't already been stated is to manually do what foreach is doing, which is useful if you need to maintain the state of the enumerator outside of the scope in which its created.

```
using(var myEnum = aList.GetEnumerator()){
    while(myEnum.MoveNext()){
        myEnum.Current.SomeAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 0...)` To use this methodology you must have an array that you can access each element of, one by one.

`foreach (SomeClass o in someList)`  This syntax can be used on an enumerable class, a class that implements `IEnumerable`.  [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) has a method `GetEnumerator()` that knows how to go through each element of the collection.  Now, the array above DOES implement `IEnumerable`.  The way it knows how to enumerate through the collection is how you defined it above.  However, not all `IEnumerable` classes that can use the foreach syntax can use the first method, as not all collections provide access to each element.  Consider the following function (didn't test it):

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetACoupleOfInts()
{
yield return 1;
yield return 2;
}
```

}

This method will allow you to use the `foreach` construct, as the runtime knows how to enumerate through the values of `GetACoupleInts()`, but would not allow the `for` construct.

`someList.ForEach(o => o.someAction());` -  The way I understand it, this lambda will just be converted to the same expression as  `foreach (SomeClass o in someList)`

`someList.AsParallel().ForAll(o => o.someAction());` - When deciding whether or not to use PLINQ you have to decide whether or not the "Juice is worth the squeeze."  If the amount of work in `someAction()` is trivial, then the overhead of the runtime trying to organize all of the data from the concurrent actions will be WAY too much and you would be better off doing it serially.

tl;dr - The first three will likely result in the same calls and have no real affect on performance, although they have different meanings within the framework.  The fourth option needs more consideration before being used.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of (C), which seems to read backwards to me, I can think of situations in which you might want to use each of the others.  In addition, depending on what you are doing you could also throw in standard LINQ into the mix.  For example, if your loop simply uses the list item to create some other object.

```
 (E) var someOtherCollection = someList.Select( l => transform(l) );
```

For option (A), if you need to know the position in the list as well as the using the item.  Option (B) or (E) would be what I would typically use.  Option (D) makes sense if the list is large and the actions are amenable to being parallelized (no or manageable dependencies between the items).

Since you're using a generic list all but (E) are O(N).  Count() should be an O(1) operation as it is kept internally in a variable.  On other enumerable types, you'd need to know how the data structure is constructed.  If you don't know the type of the collection, I'd use the `foreach` implementation or LINQ over the indexed implementation since the collection may not be indexed and that could turn your enumeration into a O(N<sup>2</sup>) operation.