# How to add numbers in a loop

Tags: c#

I am new in c#,

I want to add the numbers in my coding .

I dont know how to loop.

I want to add numbers in a loop for each time i want to add 500 in my Addition

I want to do something like this in loop for every time

```
   int StartTime = int.Parse("90000");
   int Add = StartTime + "500";
```

Comment: Please read some basic tutorials. You miss the most basic understanding, when you don't know how to do a loop and therefore you most likely won't understand or won't benefit from any answers here.

Comment: Why are you using strings instead of integer literals?

Comment: This question covers some for loops but, I think you need to start with the basics as Daniel Hilgarth suggests. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6058390/659190

Answer (score 3):

```
int StartTime = 90000;
int Add = StartTime;
int increment = 500;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Add = Add + increment;
}

// Add is 90,000 + 500 * 10 = 95,000.
```

The `for` loop syntax is a bit weird if you haven't seen it before. You have a thing to do on initialization, `int i = 0`, a thing to test against each time around the loop, to see if you should continue going `i < 10`, and a thing to do at the end of each pass around the loop, `i++` (which is a shorter way of writing `i = i + 1;`).

So here, First there is a loop variable created, `i`. Then if `i` is less than 10, the computer goes inside the loop (and sets `Add = Add + increment`). Then, the computer adds 1 to `i`, so `i` is now 1. Then checks if `i` is still less than 10. If it is, it goes into the loop again... and so on.

When `i` eventually reaches 10, the condition `i < 10` no longer holds, so the computer exists the loop.

So if we write this:

```
int StartTime = 90000;
int Add = StartTime;
int increment = 500;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(Add + " " + i);
    Add = Add + increment;
}
Console.WriteLine(Add);
```

The output is this:

```
90000 0
90500 1
91000 2
91500 3
92000 4
92500 5
93000 6
93500 7
94000 8
94500 9
95000
```

Note that the loop variable `i` only exists inside the loop, so if you were to do:

```
int StartTime = 90000;
int Add = StartTime;
int increment = 500;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(Add + " " + i);
    Add = Add + increment;
}
Console.WriteLine(Add + " " + i);
```

The program would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 10; //amount of times you want to loop

int StartTime = 90000;

int Add = 0;

for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    Add = Add + 500;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't even compile, nor does it make sense..

Comment: @codymanix - How does this not work?  Which line?

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense, but it now compiles.  I'm disappointed in myself that it took two or three passes to spot all the problems lol, my head compiler needs a reboot.

Comment: @m.edmondson: Now that Adam corrected it, it at least compiles.

Comment: I made some small typo's and left the int.Parse() in there as I though that was what the OP required - you were so quick to pounce with negativity!

Comment: The problem was that you left in the string ("500"). You just copied the "non-sense" from the OP and put a loop around it.

Comment: IMO there were actually a number of problems with the answer: not compiling, not meeting requirements (incrementing Add instead of just adding 500 to StartTime all the time), and most importantly, not explaining what was going on where the OP clearly needs some tutelage on at least loops and literal values.  But my downvote was for compilation until I decided to correct after reading the site FAQ about editing answers.

Comment: I realised that - but `int.Parse()` is valid, I assumed that string would be passed in from somewhere hence would need the conversion.  The StartTime being in the middle of the loop was a typo which I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world are you parsing strings to integer?

And why do you make so many lines?

```
int StartTime = 90000; //use an integer, not a string!
int Add = StartTime;

for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) //looping 10 times, from 0 to 10, incrementing i for 1 every time
{
    Add += 500; //so you add 500 to Add every loop
}
Console.WriteLine(Add);
```

Result:

```
95000
```