# if statement performance in c#

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I'm just trying to determine the impact of each "if" statement on the performance of my C# application when it is used in cycles with large number of iterations. I have not found the topic about this so I have created this one.

For the test I made 2 cycles: one without "if" and one with a single "if" statement. The code is the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace IfPerformance
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N = 500000000;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            double a = 0, b = 0;
            bool f;

            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                a += 1.1;
                f = a < N;
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Without if: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

            a = 0;
            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                if (a < N)
                    a += 1.1;
                else
                    b += 1.1;
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("With if:    " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I ran the test with "Optimize code" build option and "Start without debugging". The result is the following:
Without if: 154 ms
With if:    742 ms

This means that a single "if" statement brings almost 5 times slowdown to the performance. I think regarding this will be helpful.

Also, I have noticed that the presence of several extra "if"s in a large loop may slow down my final application by 25%, which on my opinion is significant.

To be specific, I'm running Monte-Carlo optimization on a set of data, which require many loops through the whole data set. The loop contains branching which depends on the user settings. From this point "if"s arise.

My questions to the professionals in performance aspects are:

1. What is the impact of extra "if"s in a loop on the time of running many iterations?
2. How to avoid the slowdown?

Please post your opinion if I'm going in the wrong direction.

Comment: You are determining the impact of every 500000000 if statements here.

Comment: These code sample are two different codes one is a boolean assignment and the other one is condition statement so this is not suitable method to evaluate performance.

Comment: Don't get hung up on micro optimisations like this. The compiler will probably optimise a lot of your code anyway. You can't performance test reliably in debug mode. The best performance testing is done using an external tool on your entire program after you have guaged user expectation

Comment: I have added boolean assignment to compensate the time for comparison operation in the second cycle and to determine the speed of pure "if" statement

Comment: Could you also be seeing an anomaly due to the JIT compiler?  What happens if you switch the order of the tests?

Comment: So you've determined that executing an if-statement costs 1.484 **nanoseconds**...

Comment: @Sico I ran this code in Release mode and compiler did NOT optimize the code so that the second cycle takes about the same time as the first one

Comment: @Steve Wortham Switching the order of the tests makes no difference

Comment: thought c/asm guys were nerd enough to clock IFs and JMPs. seems some java/dotnet guys are too!

Comment: I suggest _first_ running once without counting time to warm up the CPU. The numbers are going to change I bet.

Comment: @ja72 first running once to warm up the CPU makes no significant change

Comment: Did you change the order of operations and see if the same difference is still there?

Comment: Also look at elapsed ticks since your CPU frequency might change drastically during the benchmark. So you can measure `effort` instead of time.

Comment: @ja72 after changing the order of operations the same slowdown takes place. Measuring ticks gives the same results

Comment: In a good compiler your code would terminate instantly since it doesn't actually do something. This makes your benchmark a pretty bad one, The cost of `if` statements is also very tricky to measure, since it depends a lot on how well branch prediction and speculative execution work for this particular code and data pattern. But in general `if` is quite expensive and I try to avoid it in high performance code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't matter ...
You're testing 500 MILLION iterations ... and it takes less than a second ... IN THE WORST case ...

As comments said, you'll be in a hell of a trouble to begin with, since you won't be running in debug for testing performance, and even then, you'll have heaps of other things to take into consideration (it's a whole big world about performance testing, and it's not as simple as it seems usually).

Now, do notice that you're doing two different things in the two places. If you would like to see the performance of the if, you should have them do basically the same. I'm sure the branching changes the IL code to begin with ...

Last, but not least, as I said again ... it DOESTN'T MATTER ... unless you really need to run 500 MILLION times, and have this in so many places that your program starts to slow down because of that.

Go for readability over obsessing if you can save some micro seconds on an if statement

Feel free to read these articles by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) (*who has "only" 250K rep and i̶s̶  was a principal developer on the C# compiler team :)* who'll get you on the right direction:

- [c# performance benchmarks mistakes part 1](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one)
- [c# performance benchmarks mistakes part 2](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two)
- [c# performance benchmarks mistakes part 3](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1317/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-three)
- [c# performance benchmarks mistakes part 4](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1433/performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-four)

(Talking about this, I would guess that garbage collection (article 4) might have been something to consider ...)

Then look at: [this elaborate answer about the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15247691/1698987)

And last, but not least, have a look at [Writing Faster Managed Code: Know What Things Cost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx). This is by Jan Gray, from the Microsoft CLR Performance Team. I'll be honest and say I didn't read this one *yet* :). I Will though, later on...

It goes on an on ... :)

Comment: Thank you good ser. Always happy to help and share the wisdow :)

Comment: @Noctis 1) I really do need millions of iterations (I run some optimization processes on a set of data) 2) As I've mentioned, I run in Release mode 3) In my final application the presence of several "if"s in the loop brings 25% overall slowdown, which in my opinion is substantial. Thank you a lot for good links.

Comment: My pleasure. Regarding your comments: 1) ok. 2) ok. 3) as others mentioned, your matching oranges to potatoes (the if is/else comments), which is what Eric mentioned in: Know what you're measuring.

Comment: @Kudral Then post a question about (a simplified version of) your real application. Your benchmark doesn't represent any real workload. At least with integer operations it's often possible to eliminate `if`s by using a bit of bitshifting and masking. I do that quite often in my crypto code.

Comment: I'm benchmarking quite a lot as well and my preferences differ from Eric's in some points. For example I often use the wall clock (`UtcNow`) and ignore that the first run is different. These only matter for short running benchmarks, and not for benchmarks that run for a minute. Eric also forgot to mention some of the most important mistakes I run into, such as forgetting to disable Turbo Boost or having a background program steal a bit of CPU time.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out; I note that I *was* a member of the C# compiler development team; I am not at present.

Comment: @EricLippert fine,fine, was ... even put it in nice strike out. Amusing to see this questions keep popping up, even after people take the time to write 4 articles about them :)

Comment: @Noctis Dead links "c# performance benchmarks mistakes part..."

Comment: @SarveshMishra my my, you're right ...apparently Eric moved it to Tech.pro, but they are not showing ... i'll keep an eye open, and if it's still like that in a couple of days raise it or try to find a copy :). Cheers mate.

Comment: @EricLippert Hey Eric, seems like the links are broken, and the tech.pro ones ain't working at all (one even takes to a dodgy looking google search page)

Comment: Use the wayback machine from the internet archive and you can read it: https://web.archive.org/web/20130825155242/http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

Comment: @QuesterDesura Hallelujah ... funny the obvious answer didn't hit me in the face when i wrote those comments :)

Answer (score 3):

These code sample are two different codes one is a boolean assignment and the other one is condition statement so this is not suitable method to evaluate performance

Answer (score 2):

Those benchmarks tell you essentially nothing at all.
There are much more things at play than just an additional if.
You also have to take branch-prediction and caching into account. 
Such micro optimizations will only hinder you writing good code.
You will spend more time optimizing useless stuff than you spend time implementing good features in your software...

Think of it this way, no kind of optimization will help you if you have even a single design mistake in your code.
For example using a unfitting datastructure (for example a list for 'fast' lookup instead of a dictionary).