# Will C# compiler optimize this operation inside a loop?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

What is the best approach between the code below where `verticesInnerSides.Length / 2` is written in it's complete form each time :

```
for (int i = 0; i < verticesRoof.Length; i++) {
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + verticesInnerSides.Length / 2] = startInside;
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + verticesInnerSides.Length / 2 + 1] = startInside + Vector3.up * HEIGHT_ROOF;
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + verticesInnerSides.Length / 2 + 2] = endInside;
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + verticesInnerSides.Length / 2 + 3] = endInside + Vector3.up * HEIGHT_ROOF;
}
```

Or the following where it's written outside the loop once :

```
myCalculatedVar = verticesInnerSides.Length / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < verticesRoof.Length; i++) {
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + myCalculatedVar] = startInside;
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + myCalculatedVar + 1] = startInside + Vector3.up * HEIGHT_ROOF;
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + myCalculatedVar + 2] = endInside;
    verticesInnerSides[i * NB_VERTICES + myCalculatedVar + 3] = endInside + Vector3.up * HEIGHT_ROOF;
}
```

Will C# compiler optimize this operation in the first case ?

Comment: Why hope the compiler optimizes it for you instead off writing it properly in the first place?

Comment: open ILDSM and check for yourself <br/> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It appears you are using the parallel array anti pattern. Please consider using objects and OOP.

Comment: @Vignesh.N, most optimizations applied at CLR layer, not at C# to IL compilation (method inlining for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to reach readability and performance is:

```
myCalculatedVar = verticesInnerSides.Length / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < verticesRoof.Length; i++) {
    int ind = i * NB_VERTICES + myCalculatedVar;
    verticesInnerSides[ind] = startInside;
    verticesInnerSides[ind + 1] = startInside + Vector3.up * HEIGHT_ROOF;
    verticesInnerSides[ind + 2] = endInside;
    verticesInnerSides[ind + 3] = endInside + Vector3.up * HEIGHT_ROOF;
}
```

But you can waste your time and write some benchmarks test for testing this piece. I am sure that if a bottleneck will exist it will be in another place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why would you do it like the first code example to begin with ? The second one (without looking at the compiler) seems more efficient.
2. As per Code Complete, and many other suggestions: Don't optimize if you don't need to.
3. If you need to, simply benchmark. (There's plenty of threads, blogs and answers about what to look out for when benchmarking, but I'm sure you'll be able to find them :)

As an extra bonus, here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158562/1698987) with all the links you'll need :)

Comment: I don't agree with the conventional wisdom that pre-mature optimization "is the root of all evil". Most optimizations come with no cost (like this). They are obvious and also can increase readability, maintainability and safeness. You only have one variable to check or change instead of multiple places in the code. If you don't _optimize_ now, you'll probably never optimize it. It's much more difficult to understand   if you can change something  without causing problems if you look at the code later.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I absolutely agree about readability. Code should be written to be read. If when you're done, you have a performance issue, find out where, and then optimize that bit. Otherwise, you might be wasting time and making your code harder to read, and at the same time, maybe even slower.