# How to process all data in a big dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Can anyone help me with how to fast process all data in a big dictionary? I think a foreach loop is a slow method.

```
Dictionary<string, Student> dict = new Dictionary<string Student>();
foreach(var key in dict.keys) {
  //do something with key
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient loop in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247247/what-is-the-most-efficient-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are truly processing each item, the follow will get you the keys and values in one shot:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict) 
{
    // do something with kvp.Key?
    // do something with kvp.Value?
}
```

If asynchronous operations will be helpful something like [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) might be the tool you need.

Comment: thanks, your answer is very good. I think Parallel.ForEach is what I need.